# Which family of orthogonal polynomials satisfies these conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $P_i:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be the degree $i$ polynomial of a family of orthogonal polynomials for which the following conditions hold:

- The root of $P_1$ is $0$.
- When $n\geq2$, the roots $x_1,\ldots ,x_n$ of $P_n$ satisfies

$$\frac{x_i}{x_n}=\sin  \left(\pi  \left(\frac{i-1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

How to determine which family of orthogonal polynomials this is?

**Edit** After choosing $P_0(x)=1,P_1(x)=x$, numerical experiments reveals that $P_2$ can be chosen as any, even quadratic polynomial. The recurrence relation for the rest is $$P_n(x)=xP_{n-1}(x)-P_{n-2}\begin{cases}
 0 & n=3 \\
 c & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

where $c$ doesn't depend on $n$. Because of the $0$ the roots of $P_2$ are also roots of the remaining $P$s, so no family of orthogonal polynomials exist.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when talking about "*orthogonal*"? Orthogonal with respect to the $L^2$ dot product on the interval $[-1,1]$?

Comment: @ComplexFlo With respect to some weighted $L^2$ dot product

Comment: What weight function do you use? The first condition tells you that $P_1(x) = ax$ for some constant $a$. Moreover, $P_2(x) = a_2 x^2 + b_2 x + c_2$ and $\langle P_1, P_2 \rangle = 0$ by definition. Moreover, $x_1/x_2 = -1$ by the second condition. Now you can use these properties in order to compute the roots $x_1, x_2$ of $P_2$.

Comment: I guess the question goes like this: $P_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.  Given a density on $[-1,1]$, this determines (up to constants) the sequence $P_n$ or orthogonal polynomials. (Gram-Schmidt on the sequence $1, x, x^2, x^3,\dots$.)  The question is: which density (if any)  will produce the polynomials with these zeros?

Comment: I assume you tried the standard orthogonal polynomials to see whether they are the ones? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials#Examples_of_orthogonal_polynomials

Comment: @GEdgar I tried jacobi, chebyshev 1st and 2nd and legendre all of which ended up with equation with no solution